# How do I Mute/UnMute Notifications in Android Wear

Tags: android, notifications, wear-os

Andoid Wear allows the user to Mute and Unmute notifications on the watch.  Is there a way to do this from my app?  I want to include a user setting that lets them to choose whether or not to be interrupted while using the app. I cannot find a clear way to do this in the API docs.

Comment: they can choose that by changing it themselves on the wearable device

Comment: I want to do this for the user instead of making them do it every time.

Answer (score 0):

The main mute and unmute is a system setting so the app will not be able to change that programmatically without rooting. That said, if you purely wanted to mute your own app on wear but continue to display the notification on your mobile device, you can choose to display the notification on the mobile / tablet device and not the wearables by setting [setLocalOnly](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setLocalOnly(boolean)) to true.

Comment: Thanks for the info @hoi.  It would be a nice feature to add.  I can see multiple use cases where you would want notifications to auto mute (i.e. location based).